clangd false positive '<quadmath.h>' not found
I have a C++ project, using CMake, GCC and Arch Linux. I am using GCC and the project is compiling correctly (both in IDE and command line), but I have these errors in Qt Creator:
heat_transfer_explicit_scheme.cpp:1:10: In included file: 'quadmath.h' file not found
float128.hpp:54:10: error occurred here
...
heat_transfer_explicit_scheme.cpp:1:10: In included file: no member named 'value' in 'boost::multiprecision::number_category<backends::float128_backend>'
number.hpp:131:399: error occurred here

But this header is present in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include, and clicking on #include <quadmath.h> will open it in the IDE.
As I understand, /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include is not the default sysroot, and clangd does not know about this location, so I tried to add CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include like on this forum thread: Qt Forum — Qt Creator - clang code model doesn't find types, even though code compiles. But it doesn't make <quadmath.h> location accessible to clangd.
Moreover, after setting CMAKE_SYSROOT in CMakeLists.txt pointing to their location, other project dependencies (like boost) can't be found by find_package.
Also, I tried to add /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include to PATH of current terminal session and open Qt Creator from this env, but it seems to have no effect.
Qt Creator version 14.0.1 based on Qt 6.7.2 (GCC 14.2.1 20240805, x86_64).
Clangd not indexing these files with clang++ compiler because he have his own realizations and not needed gcc intrinsic headers codechecker. But I am using g++ in project and want clangd to handle the indexing.

Sysroot is a directory which contains file hierarchy similar to one under the real root directory (/). That is, under a sysroot one could expect to find usr/local/, bin/ and similar subdirectories. As you could find, the directory /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include doesn't have this property, so making it a sysroot is just wrong.

@Tsyvarev yep, but this was the first idea how to include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include to search path, because include_directories or target_include_directories not worked

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include is gcc 14's "built-in include directory". Clangd deliberately ignores this, even if you point it at the gcc 14 installation using --query-driver, because many files in this directory contain gcc-only intrinsics that the clang frontend cannot parse.
(If you're curious, the reasons for clangd ignoring this directory are discussed in more detail at https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1695)
You can override this behaviour by adding this directory to the include path in the compile commands used by clangd. A simple way to do this is to create a .clangd file in the project root containing:
CompileFlags:
  Add: -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include


Adding .clangd with given source supress erros with no find files, but rise definition built-in functions _rdtsc, another _mm_getcsr. How i should point clangd --query-driver? I am set workspace configuration in json format: {
"clangd.arguments": ["--query-driver=usr/bin/gcc,usr/bin/g++"]
} in project's language server options. Also trying to add to .clangd: __# Suppress: 'builtin_definition'
Add: [--query-driver=usr/bin/gcc,usr/bin/g++]__ but no effects

link if add to .clangd                                 Diagnostics:   Suppress: builtin_definition this warnings gone. But i dont know is it good or bad practice?

@AlexanderKolbeko Well, like I said, "files in this directory contain gcc-only intrinsics that the clang frontend cannot parse". Clangd is a clang-based tool. If you're writing code that cannot be compiled with clang, you're not going to get a perfect experience editing it with clangd. Maybe there is a portable equivalent to <quadmath.h> that you could consider using, that works with both gcc and clang?

<quadmath.h> headers required from boost.multiprecision, and as i read from source code this headers required only on gcc, clang has his own built-in stuff. I understand that it was possible select clang, but i just want to know how fix this kind of problems with gcc,like this .clangd file otions, or use another language server?

@AlexanderKolbeko If boost.multiprecision supports clang, my recommendation would be to configure it once to use clang, and generate the compile_commands.json from that configuration for clangd's use. You can always configure it again to use gcc for the actual build.

this file need to be re-generated all time when i add new files to project. I think here is just unsupported use case, so i think your answer + disable builtin_definition is a solution

This is a GCC header only, If I were you, I would try to use some preprocessor to disable the #include <quadmath.h> on Clang, and fix the code accordingly (and send PR to upstream project?).
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#include <quadmath.h>
#endif

Ref: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libquadmath/quadmath.h

I am using g++ compiler with gnu++20 standard, it successfully compiling code, <quadmath.h> is intrinsic gcc headers also present in system. QtСreator using clangd language server by default (not clang compiler, but it can be picked in kit configuration) for code indexing.
